# Python - identify the type of device

Tags: python, macos

My apologies if I haven't used correct terminology.

I am writing a small python script to copy files from external harddrive to Mac.

I get the external hard drive list by using -

```
import os
os.listdir('/Volumes')
```

I get the following list -

```
BOOTCAMP
FREEAGENT
Mobilebackup
PCQ
```

PCQ....is DVD.MobileBackup, not sure what it is. I cant see it in left pane of finder. I want to know the type of volume or device, so that I can just use the external hard-drive and ignore everything else.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the output of `diskutil list`, perhaps you can parse it to get what you want.

For parsing diskutil you can specify the `-plist` option and then use `plistlib` to convert to a Python dictionary:

```
import plistlib
import pprint
import subprocess

output = subprocess.check_output(('/usr/sbin/diskutil', 'list', '-plist'))
diskutil = plistlib.readPlistFromString(output)
pprint.pprint(diskutil)
```